# Asterisk: "TLS clean shutdown alert reading data" after 120s in SIP call

Tags: ssl, twilio, asterisk, sip

I am using a Secure SIP trunk provided by Twilio to implement an IVR. I have implemented per Twilio's Asterisk configuration guide, installed SRTP to /usr/local/lib, as well as implemented the configuration in https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Secure+Calling+Tutorial.

The problem lies in any call that is longer than 2 minutes cannot be ended cleanly and causes Asterisk to restart.

sip.conf (using chan_sip, not pjsip):

```
[general]
; other configuration lines removed
tlsenable=yes
tlsbindaddr=0.0.0.0
tlscertfile=/etc/pki/tls/private/pbx.pem
tlscafile=/etc/pki/tls/private/gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt
tlscipher=ALL
tlsclientmethod=tlsv1 
tlsdontverifyserver=yes


[twilio-trunk](!)
type=peer
context=from-twilio ;Which dialplan to use for incoming calls
dtmfmode=rfc4733
canreinvite=no
insecure=port,invite
transport=tls
qualify=yes
encryption=yes
media_encryption=sdes
```

I can make and receive calls just fine, and I have confirmed the calls are encrypted both via wireshark and confirmation from Twilio's own support queue.

At exactly 120 seconds into every call, this debug pops up:

```
[Dec 6 13:14:39] DEBUG[30015]: iostream.c:157 iostream_read: TLS clean shutdown alert reading data
[Dec 6 13:14:39] DEBUG[30015]: chan_sip.c:2905 sip_tcptls_read: SIP TCP/TLS server has shut down
```

The call continues to flow bi-directionally, the caller never knows there is a problem until they hit a hangup in context, i.e. h,1,Hangup(). Then Asterisk is restarted (new PID) and the caller hangs in limbo for another 5 minutes before the call times out with a fast busy. Twilio confirms they see the BYE and return an ACK at the point of the Hangup.

I was on 13.11 and updated to 15.1.3, same result. Calls longer than 120s result in TLS message in debug and Asterisk restarts.

No Google query results out there. Twilio hasn't been real helpful. Can anyone shed some light on what is happening and where I need to look next?

More logs:

```
[Dec 8 10:18:48] DEBUG[4993][C-00000001]: channel.c:5551 set_format: Channel SIP/twilio0-00000000 setting write format path: gsm -> ulaw
[Dec 8 10:18:48] DEBUG[4993][C-00000001]: res_rtp_asterisk.c:4017 rtp_raw_write: Difference is 2472, ms is 329
[Dec 8 10:18:48] DEBUG[4993][C-00000001]: channel.c:3192 ast_settimeout_full: Scheduling timer at (50 requested / 50 actual) timer ticks per second
– <SIP/twilio0-00000000> Playing ‘IVR/omnicare_9d_account.gsm’ (language ‘en’)
[Dec 8 10:18:48] DEBUG[4993][C-00000001]: res_rtp_asterisk.c:4928 ast_rtcp_interpret: Got RTCP report of 64 bytes from 34.203.250.7:10475
[Dec 8 10:18:53] DEBUG[4993][C-00000001]: res_rtp_asterisk.c:4928 ast_rtcp_interpret: Got RTCP report of 64 bytes from 34.203.250.7:10475
[Dec 8 10:18:55] DEBUG[4992]: iostream.c:157 iostream_read: TLS clean shutdown alert reading data
[Dec 8 10:18:55] DEBUG[4992]: chan_sip.c:2905 sip_tcptls_read: SIP TCP/TLS server has shut down
[Dec 8 10:18:58] DEBUG[4993][C-00000001]: channel.c:3192 ast_settimeout_full: Scheduling timer at (0 requested / 0 actual) timer ticks per second
[Dec 8 10:18:58] DEBUG[4993][C-00000001]: channel.c:3192 ast_settimeout_full: Scheduling timer at (0 requested / 0 actual) timer ticks per second
[Dec 8 10:18:58] DEBUG[4993][C-00000001]: channel.c:3192 ast_settimeout_full: Scheduling timer at (0 requested / 0 actual) timer ticks per second
[Dec 8 10:18:58] DEBUG[4993][C-00000001]: channel.c:5551 set_format: Channel SIP/twilio0-00000000 setting write format path: ulaw -> ulaw
[Dec 8 10:18:58] DEBUG[4993][C-00000001]: res_rtp_asterisk.c:4928 ast_rtcp_interpret: Got RTCP report of 64 bytes from 34.203.250.7:10475
[Dec 8 10:19:01] DEBUG[4914]: cdr.c:4305 ast_cdr_engine_term: CDR Engine termination request received; waiting on messages…
Asterisk uncleanly ending (0).
Executing last minute cleanups
== Destroying musiconhold processes
[Dec 8 10:19:01] DEBUG[4914]: res_musiconhold.c:1627 moh_class_destructor: Destroying MOH class ‘default’
[Dec 8 10:19:01] DEBUG[4914]: cdr.c:1289 cdr_object_finalize: Finalized CDR for SIP/twilio0-00000000 - start 1512749813.880448 answer 1512749813.881198 end 1512749941.201797 dispo ANSWERED
== Manager unregistered action DBGet
== Manager unregistered action DBPut
== Manager unregistered action DBDel
== Manager unregistered action DBDelTree
[Dec 8 10:19:01] DEBUG[4914]: asterisk.c:2157 really_quit: Asterisk ending (0).
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your firewall logs. We've had issues with sessions being torn down by firewalls that thought the NAT entries were stale/old.

You can also try configuring Asterisk to send keep-alive packets using the option `qualify=yes` and `nat=yes` in your *sip.conf* entry for that user/trunk. Or inside the RTP stream with `rtpkeepalive=<secs>`. The best docs I could find for sip.conf are the example config on [github](https://github.com/asterisk/asterisk/blob/master/configs/samples/sip.conf.sample).

I dug in [the source code](https://github.com/asterisk/asterisk/blob/710b3a29c34082029c8595b640f4767d548dcc2f/main/iostream.c) for the text "TLS clean shutdown alert reading data", which pointed me to [some OpenSSL docs](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/ssl/SSL_get_error.html#RETURN-VALUES) which suggest a clean/normal closure (which I'm guessing was caused by your firewall):

> The TLS/SSL connection has been closed. If the protocol version is SSL 3.0 or higher, this result code is returned only if a closure alert has occurred in the protocol, i.e. if the connection has been closed cleanly. Note that in this case SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN does not necessarily indicate that the underlying transport has been closed.

Comment: Another test you could try is to take the firewall out of the equation by configuring a second PBX to talk to locally with as close to the same config as possible. This would rule out issues in the pbx and suggest network meddling from the firewall.